# Droidcam Installation Error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, webcam, droidcam

I've been trying to install Droidcam on my Ubuntu 18.04 and I've encountered an error I can't solve:

```
root@homelab:/tmp/droidcam-64bit#  sudo ./install
Webcam parameters: '640' and '480'
Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
make: Entering directory '/tmp/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback'
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
Makefile:970: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /tmp/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/droidcam-64bit/v4l2loopback'
Moving driver and executable to system folders
Registering webcam device
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Since my microphone doesn't work I am mainly using Droidcam to emulate a mic on my linux machine using my phone. I don't need the webcam capabillities either, so if I could just create a fake device I'd be happy. I just need to stream my audio through my phone to my linux machine. If I try to open Droidcam right now, I'm getting the following error: **Device not found (/dev/video[0-9]). Did you install it?**

Your help would be much appreciated :) Also, [here's](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/) the tutorial I followed to install Droidcam (it's the official website).

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar problem but in a bit different scenario. I was running already installed Droidcam on Ubuntu and saw this error. It was caused due to a lost video device which happened after **kernel update**.

So that, I uninstalled Droidcam-

```
sudo /opt/droidcam-uninstall
```

Then reinstalled it following [this](http://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/) procedure.

The problem was solved afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800731/module-not-found-when-i-do-a-modprobe

Running this:

```
sudo depmod -ae
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback_dc
droidcam
```

It is working for me.

Comment: Gave me an error, `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback_dc': Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 2):

Just tried to use droid cam and hit same bugs. What got me going was to first install standard loopback camera from apt.

```
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-utils
```

doing install prompt for the MOK password. Then reboot and get another prompt about MOK password. Don't skip the password.

After that, I did the droid cam instructions again from the link above and the module was no more error.

I had usb debuggin on the old alcatel phone and I can find it in cheese program camera list. Here is the firs picture.

[image: first picture using droid cam shows askubuntu post.]

Now need to see about the resolution. onlye seeing 640x480 in the list of cheese settings.

**install/update script**

```
#!/bin/bash

# original command line option getter filename: commandLine.sh
# thanks to author: @theBuzzyCoder

showHelp() {
# `cat << EOF` This means that cat should stop reading when EOF is
# detected
cat << EOF  
Usage: ./droidcam.sh [-hbir -x N -y N]
Get a new droid cam if needed and change resolution if desired.

-h, -help,          --help              Display help

-b, -build,         --build             Download and rebuild droidcam

-i, -install,       --install           Install droidcam kernel modules

-r, -resolution,    --resolution        Set new resolution

-x, -xres,          --xres [N]          Pixel width resolution

-y, -yres,          --yres [N]          Pixel height resolution
EOF
# EOF is found above and hence cat command stops reading. 
# This is equivalent to echo but much neater when printing out.
}

if [[ ! $@ =~ ^\-.+ ]]
then
    echo
    echo Needs argugments
    echo
    showHelp
    exit 0
fi

export build=0
export installit=0
export resolution=0
export XRES=1920
export YRES=1080

# $@ is all command line parameters passed to the script.
# -o is for short options like -v
# -l is for long options with double dash like --version
# the comma separates different long options
# -a is for long options with single dash like -version
options=$(getopt -l "help,build,install,resolution,xpixels:,ypixels:" -o "hbirx:y:" -a -- "$@")

# set --:
# If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are unset. Otherwise, the positional parameters 
# are set to the arguments, even if some of them begin with a ‘-’.
eval set -- "$options"

while true
do
case $1 in
-h|--help) 
    showHelp
    exit 0
    ;;
-b|--build) 
    export build=1
    echo BUILD=$build
    ;;
-i|--install)
    export installit=1
    ;;
-r|--resolution)
    export resolution=1
    ;;
-x|--xres)
    shift
    export XRES=$1
    ;;
-y|--yres)
    shift
    export YRES=$1
    ;;
--)
    shift
    break;;
esac
shift
done

# run the build when there is a kernel update

if [ $build -gt 0 ]; then
    cd /tmp/
    wget https://files.dev47apps.net/linux/droidcam_latest.zip
    unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam
    cd droidcam && sudo ./install-client
    sudo ./install-video
fi

# doing installation or change resolution

if [ $installit -gt 0 ] || [ $resolution -gt 0 ]; then
    sudo rmmod v4l2loopback_dc
    sudo insmod /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko width=$XRES height=$YRES
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem just now, and if you have a Secure Boot enabled you might wanna uninstall the droidcam first then
run this command

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
```

then reboot you should see the Mok Manager then proceed to enroll key
and sign it and continue booting up then re-install the droidcam