# Droidcam UEFI secure boot error

Tags: boot, software-installation, kernel, uefi, droidcam

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 with Dual boot Windows 10 on a Lenovo machine and trying to use [THESE](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/) instructions to install Droidcam. When I do the installation, I get an error which says:

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko: Operation not permitted
>
> warning: insmod failed

After that I tried to run the software via terminal but got the following error prompt:

[image: error prompt]

I think the error has something to do with the UEFI secure boot.

When I do `lsmod | grep v4l2loopback_dc` I don't get any output, indicating that Droidcam isn't really installed.

Can someone please help me with the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Droidcam is working now.

First, I uninstalled Droidcam.

Second, [Using the answer by Earl Sablo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133007/droidcam-installation-error-on-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1) I tried the following:

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
```

It asked to create a password for the secure boot menu, which I created.

Then I restarted my PC and the secure boot menu asked threw a number of options. Choose "Enter MOK key", and use the password created earlier.

Finally, reboot and reinstall Droidcam. It works fine now.

Comment: Did you installed via ./install or ./install-dkms? I tried both and didn't work

Comment: ./install

Check this -- https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/

What error are you getting?

Comment: I was able to do it now, but I have to install using ./install-dkms and after that, the ./install worked

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following command exited without an error message.

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
```

so I tried [Manfred Hampl's answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/692638) and it worked.

First enter the following command:

```
sudo su
mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
```

Everything else is the same as Shihab Khan's answer.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 with dual boot with windows 10.